# How do I incorporate jQuery with CodeIgniter?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Hey guys I seem to have a bit of a problem. When I try to use jQuery at all it won't work for nothing. Everything is linked fine, jQuery is setup fine and what not. But when I do a simple `$(document).ready(function(){});` and I look at the console I see this

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
```

Does anybody have any idea what I could be?

My code looks like this

```
    <script type="text/javasript" src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascipt" src="<?=base_url()?>js/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            alert(1);
        });
    </script>
```

******* SOLUTION FOUND *********
I figured it out, everything was linked properly but for some odd reason because I have the template set up as a header and footer page separately it wouldn't work, so I have to include jQuery manually on the current page I'm using (excluding header and footer). But it seems to work fine. Thanks for the help guys :)

Comment: try to change `$` to `jQuery`,what's happen?

Comment: can you post the generated HTML (source of the document that is rendered?)

Comment: Your solution doesn't make sense, including the page header with all its css and js files is common practice and can't be the reason why js won't work.

Comment: @stef Exactly what I was thinking I always make my templates separate with a header and footer file. I look and the HTML generated and everything is linked and structured just fine. I find it extremely odd that it only does this to me on CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

there is no jQuery in your page! ensure your html look like this:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // we will add our javascript code here
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- we will add our HTML content here -->
    </body>

</html>
```

jQuery must head of you custom code.

follow this [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery),that can be a lot help.

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't specific enough jQuery is linked perfectly fine

Comment: @Tim are you sure? Please check in Firebug or in similar tools.

Comment: @uzsolt I figured it out, everything was linked properly but for some odd reason because I have the template set up as a header and footer page separately on the current I'm using I have to include it manually. But it seems to work fine. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

try to use jquery.noConflict()

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      $.noConflict();
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
      });
      // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```